# jQuery addClass some problems

Tags: jquery

I wanted to pass in a function to .addClass() to add the "green" class to a div that already has a "red" class.
here is my code
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wv2s5/4)

```
$( "two" ).addClass(function( index, currentClass ) {
  var addedClass;

  if ( currentClass === "red" ) {
    addedClass = "green";
  }

  return addedClass;
});
```

And this is my html

```
<div class='one'>Hi there</div>
<div class='two red'>Hello</div>
```

And this is my css

```
 .red {
    background: red;
 }
 .green {
    background: green;
 }
```

Comment: have you load jquery? Try use function hasClass instead.

Comment: i tried to write code like this here [demo](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because value of b is `two black` and you comparing it with black which return always false, so try:

```
var one = $('.one');
var two = $('.two');
two.addClass(function (a, b) {
    var s;      
    if (b.indexOf('black')>0) {
        s = 'red';
    }
    return s;
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Wv2s5/1/)

But you should know that it will add class to your element so after this you class will be `two black red` if you dont want black there than remove it using:

```
$(this).removeClass('black')
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Wv2s5/3/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class='one'>Hi there</div>
<div class='two black'>Hello</div>

$('.black').removeClass('black').addClass('red');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCa37/)

Comment: If it doesn't work then it's probably incorrect.. You can replace classes in one simple line of code as I suggested.

Comment: i tried to write code like that [demo](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) but they actually used this code.

Comment: The demo used the same function, but the elem had only one class and therefore you could use === for comparing. In your case, you have two classes(b == 'two black'), so you can either use indexOf, or think of a better way.
This is a simple debug, so if i were you, I would learn how to debug javascript ASAP..

Comment: Actually no one can clearly explained me. I really not understand. Thanx anyway.

Comment: You did this: b === 'black' and it's wrong since your div has more than one class(<div class='two black'>Hello</div>).
In your case b === 'two black' and instead of asking what you asked(b === 'black'), you need to ask in b contains 'black'(b.indexOf('black') > 0) - this will work. It's not the most elegant way to do it, but it will work. There are some problems with this..if you have a 'darkblack' css class then indexOf('black') will be > 0, but you probably didn't want that to happen.

Comment: Thank you now I understand something.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work.

```
var one = $('.one');
var two = $('.two');
two.addClass(function( index, currentClass ) {
    var addedClass;
    var $class = currentClass.split(' ')
    for(i in $class){
        if ( $class[i] === "black") {
            addedClass = "red";
        }
    }
    return addedClass;
});
```